# How to draw a line on image and retrieve pixels beneath the line?

Tags: python, image, opencv, python-imaging-library

I am trying to draw a line on the image and retrieve all the pixel values that fall beneath the line. I have tried but a method where you retrieve the 2 mouse click coordinates and calculate the slope between the two mouse coordinates but that is very specifically extracting only one row. How can I change the width of the line and also retrieve the pixels beneath it? I am new to python and I don't know where to start. Any ideas or any recommendations would be great thank you.

Simply to understand I want to draw a line on image and extract pixels beneath the line, and also when we change the width of line I want to extract pixel values of the extended with too. How can I do this?

```
from tkinter import *
import PIL
import PIL.Image 
import PIL.ImageTk 
root = Tk()

#setting up a tkinter canvas with scrollbars
frame = Frame(root, bd=2, relief=SUNKEN)
frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
xscroll = Scrollbar(frame, orient=HORIZONTAL)
xscroll.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E+W)
yscroll = Scrollbar(frame)
yscroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)
canvas = Canvas(frame, bd=0, xscrollcommand=xscroll.set, yscrollcommand=yscroll.set)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)
xscroll.config(command=canvas.xview)
yscroll.config(command=canvas.yview)
frame.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)

#adding the image in the below line u16 us my image array.
img = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image =PIL.Image.fromarray(u16))

canvas.create_image(0,0,image=img,anchor="nw")
canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox(ALL))

#function to be called when mouse is clicked
def printcoords(event):
    #outputting x and y coords to console
    click = event.x, event.y
    print (click)
def printcoords_up(event):
    #outputting x and y coords to console
    rem_click=event.x, event.y
    print (rem_click)
#mouseclick event
canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>",printcoords)
# canvas.bind("<ButtonMotion-1>", printcoords)
canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", printcoords_up )

root.mainloop()
```

##################EDITED CODE #####################

```
import tkinter 
import numpy as np
import cv2
import sys
import PIL
import PIL.Image 
import PIL.ImageTk as imtk
if "Tkinter" not in sys.modules:
    from tkinter import *

curPth = sys.path[0]
###### u16 is my image array.
im = u16
tmpPth = curPth+'/temp.png'

ev = None


def click(event, back):
    global ev, im
    if ev == None:
       ev = event
       return None

# im = imgPth
# mask = cv2.cvtColor(im.copy()*0, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.line(im, pt1=(ev.x, ev.y), pt2=(event.x, event.y), color=(255, 0, 0), thickness=40)
mask = cv2.threshold(im, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
out = im.copy()
out[np.where(mask == 0)] = 255

cv2.imwrite(tmpPth, out)
back.config(file=tmpPth)
print(event)
ev = event

window = tkinter.Tk()
back = imtk.PhotoImage(image =PIL.Image.fromarray(im))
my_label=Label(window, image=back)
my_label.place(x=0, y=0)
window.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: click(event, back))
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: How do you want to draw the line? Will it already be drawn when it is as an input to the program? Or should the program have an interface that lets you draw the line and also select it's thickness?

Comment: Draw the line (e.g. using OpenCV drawing functions) without antialiasing into a black single channel image. Then use this image as a mask, or for numpy indexing of the original image... depends on what exactly you want to do with the "retrieved pixel values".  While a bit brute, this will likely be faster (and much simpler) than reimplementing a line iterator in pure Python.

Comment: you **don't** want to **draw** a line you **want to sample** the picture's data along a line. calculate an affine transformation (2x3 matrix... but work with 3x3 because it's easier). apply it and set the output to be an 1xN array. that's how you can sample your picture along that defined line.

Comment: I have added the code. What my idea was to get pixel coordinates of two mouse clicks and calculate the slope and then index a array to retrieve the pixel values. I want to achieve this using tkinter only. The problem is its too specific and extracts only one row but I want to extract more rows.

Comment: How can I do that @ChristophRackwitz.

Comment: look for warpAffine in this code https://github.com/crackwitz/metrology-demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was a little confused by your question; But I guess if I misunderstood the problem; it may help someone else later. I tried to test it with **@Dan Mašek** method.

```py
from tkinter import *
import numpy as np
import cv2
import sys
import PIL.Image as imge
import PIL.ImageTk as imtk

curPth = sys.path[0]
imgPth = curPth+'/back.png'
tmpPth = curPth+'/temp.png'

ev = None
thikness = 40


def click(event):
    global ev, back, lbl
    if ev == None:
        ev = event
        return None

    im = cv2.imread(imgPth)
    mask = cv2.cvtColor(im.copy()*0, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.line(mask, pt1=(ev.x, ev.y), pt2=(event.x, event.y),
             color=(255, 0, 0), thickness=thikness)
    mask = cv2.threshold(mask, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    out = im.copy()
    out[np.where(mask == 0)] = 255

    out = cv2.cvtColor(out, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    back = imtk.PhotoImage(image=imge.fromarray(out))
    lbl.config(image=back)

    # print(mask[np.where(mask == 255)])
    x, X = min(ev.x, event.x)-thikness//2, max(ev.x, event.x)+thikness//2
    y, Y = min(ev.y, event.y)-thikness//2, max(ev.y, event.y)+thikness//2
    cropped = mask[y:Y, x:X]
    print(cropped, cropped.shape)
    cv2.imwrite(curPth+'/2d_line_area.png', cropped)
    ev = event


root = Tk()
back = PhotoImage(file=imgPth)
lbl = Label(root, image=back)
lbl.place(x=0, y=0)
root.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: click(event))
root.mainloop()
```

My test image that I draw with paint.net:
[image]

Tkinter main loop:
[image]

After click on 2 points on screen:
[image]

And more tests:
[image]

---

Two-dimensional array only from the area where the line is drawn.

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

More examples:

```py
x, X = min(ev.x, event.x)-thikness//2, max(ev.x, event.x)+thikness//2
y, Y = min(ev.y, event.y)-thikness//2, max(ev.y, event.y)+thikness//2
cropped1 = mask[y:Y, x:X]
cropped2 = out[y:Y, x:X]
print(cropped1, cropped1.shape)
cropped1=cv2.cvtColor(cropped1,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
cropped2=cv2.cvtColor(cropped2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
cv2.imwrite(curPth+'/2d_line_area.png', np.hstack((cropped1,cropped2)))
ev = event
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is what I wanted but did now know how to approach thank you so much. So while using mask if we change the width of the line it will retrieve the respective pixels too right? Thank you so much. Have a nice day!.

Comment: Hello :) Yes you can change this parameter **thickness=40**

Comment: Hi again I am trying to implement it using this method. I made a slight modification by giving a image array instead of imgpath. I get this error  AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'config'. Can you help me with this. I have added the code in the edits.

Comment: Hello :) You mean this line **imtk.PhotoImage(image =PIL.Image.fromarray(im))** ?

Comment: yes, it works great if I save image and access it from pc, But I wanted to try without saving an image array, which I already have and use it from the jupyter notebook cell. I hope you understand, but is fine I can save and use it and if I find a solution that works Ill post it here.

Comment: Thank you so much for editing. I have a small confusion , after I retrieve the pixel values using the mask it retrieves the array in one dimension is there a way to make it and retrieve it in 2d array. Like if we print the mask in the code of gives pixel values of line in 1d. How can I change it to 2d I tried converting it to array but it is already an array.

Comment: Hello :) Can you give an example? The final image is not a one-dimensional array.

Comment: Check it using the print function :)

Comment: Hi its not the saved image that i am trying to extract but it is where the line is drawn. Here in the code where there is a mask variable, so if we print mask variable we get pixel values that are not masked in the image or a line drawn by the user. It is that mask values I am getting in a 1d array which I want in a 2d array. I am sorry to ask many questions. But thank you for replying to my questions. I hope you understand what I am trying to achieve. If not I will explain again.

Comment: Hello @Blueman0002 :) let me think about it

Comment: Ok if you print shape of mask the output is -> Mask: (202, 202) and its not 1d array

Comment: And mask data is something like this [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 ...
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

Comment: Hello again. I get the shape of the mask is same as the shape of the image but I am trying to retrieve the masked coordinates where the mask is 255 as array. We can achieve this by doing np.where at mask. That result i am getting 1d array but I want that in 2d array sorry for misleading you. If you are interested we can chat over discord where I can explain my whole problem? Is that okay?

Comment: Ok I get it :) something like this mask[np.where(mask==255)] and the output is [255 255 255 ... 255 255 255]

Comment: I removed old examples and changed the code; check out new update :)

Comment: Thank you so much. Have a nice day! That is exactly as I needed.